# HFSQL Server WDSQL19 Check if the external document is available

Tags: sql-server, clipper

So we are running Clipper ERP V7 in our company. We run a HFSQL server on a central server.
I have some tables that contain filepaths to external documents.
These documents are not database files. They are pdf xlsx word, idw (inventor drawing file) dft (solid edge drawing file) etc..
Throughout the past 15 years folders were renamed so the locations in some cases does not match up with the current file locations.
Now I would like to query the server to check on the validity of these file locations.

I have WDSQL SQL Tool installed and ready to use, and have access to the HFSQL Control Center too.

The data is inside the NomFichier column in every table and looks like this Z:\Zoli\37\66161683.0\Modellek\66161683.0A.idw

I have updated a ton of locations using UPDATE and WHERE and LIKE commands combined through the  HFSQL Control Center's SQL query interface with great success, however due to the fact that we are speaking of 30K+ individual file, chances of missing something are extremely high. So I would love to know how could I test the files and print the list of missing files with paths.

Or should I rather export the table and try doing this in Excel?

Comment: HFSQL is not SQL Server i think. I would probably write a script that loads all paths from the database and then check for file destinations inside the script